# Will outbound external links reduce the link-juice of an article?

Tags: seo, links, pagerank, nofollow, link-juice

In terms of SEO, the use of external links with the `nofollow` attribute could reduce the link-juice of my internal linking?

I have two options about how to link external sources with related information:

- With a link containing a `rel="nofollow"` attribute.
- Without a link, but a number, and at the end of the post, introduce the naked URL without the link.

For example:

`1. Source: example.com`

Instead of:

`<a rel="nofollow" href="example.com">example.com</a>`

What would be more effective, for SEO?

Comment: There is no need to hoard Pagerank by withholding links to external sites, doing so doesn't help your SEO. Link in the way that is best for your users (use an actual link, not just a text mention.)  Don't use `nofollow` unless the URL is an ad or created by your users.  Even then, prefer to use `rel=sponsored` or `rel=ugc` rather than `rel=nofollow`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna fix some articles: creating real hyperlinks for external sources.